# Prevent autocomplete in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the new [Visual Studio Code](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/code-vs.aspx).

In a SQL file, any time you type <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>, it automatically adds `end`, as if you were building a `case` block. Even if you're in a comment, or using `Case` as part of a word (for example, `select CaseID from...`).

I'd like to disable all of that nonsense completely, since it doesn't do a good job of auto completing things for me.

The only configuration options I can find, I've already set:

```
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
```

What else can I do to stop this?

It is also true for things like <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> (it adds `end`), and I'm sure lots more.

Comment: A workaround is to press ^Z after typing `case` or `begin`. It's still a pain.

Answer (score 320, accepted):

In the most recent version of Visual Studio Code I've found out that the

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```

configuration disables this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I was typing `render(` and getting `CanvasRenderingContext2D` instead.  WTF?!?!?!  It wouldn't let me write what I typed without disabling on commit character.  What a horrible default.  Editors shouldn't replace what you type without your permission.

Comment: It's even worse when it changes to something bonkers and automatically inserts an import for that unwanted symbol..

Comment: @tucq88 just checked - works for version `1.29.1`. Do you mean you can not find the option or unticking the checkbox does not change the behaviour?

Comment: @shybovycha Yeah I add `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
` to settings.json manually but it doesn't work as expected. I mean its still auto-completed after I restart VScode. Not sure why.

Comment: @tucq88 what's the version of VS Code that you are using?

Comment: Thanking you kindly because `getData` + `(` => `__acrt_get_locale_data_prefix()` just isn't helping my productivity.

Comment: This worked for me, version: 1.33.0. Was typing x and period and it kept autocompleting to some random XML thing. Ridiculous.

Comment: I changed this because it was making me crazy on doing JS imports. However, I also had to add: `"editor.quickSuggestions": false,` so that every time I typed "const" I didn't get a huge and irrelevant list requiring I click `ESC` between the keyword and variable name.

Comment: Oh my days. Thank you so much, every time I try to write a test with Jest I get `TextDecoderStream` which has been doing my head in!

Comment: `"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false` was what did it for me (see Bart's comment). Ugh!

Comment: Thank you @NeilGuyLindberg!  For me, "editor.quickSuggestions" was what was needed.  I had set the acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter false and still got insane autocompletions.  I can use VSCode again now!

Comment: So where exactly are you supposed to add this? I hate when people assume people just know where to place these things.

Comment: @ThePrince if you open Settings page in your VSCode (File -> Preferences -> Settings), there is a big search bar at the top of the page. Type in the setting name (as suggested in the answer) and VSCode will show you the most relevant option(s). Alternatively, you can edit `settings.json` file (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations ) and just add or modify the option there.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the suggestions have got smarter now that it's not trying to figure every single character.

Answer (score 96):

By 2016, Visual Studio Code is pretty cool and ready for prime time. But I still haven't found a way to simply turn off autocompletion completely.

But they do have some things in their documentation:
*[Customizing IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense)*

Basically, I put this in my `settings.json` to try and turn it off for the workspace. But I still have to evaluate this.

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
    // Controls if quick suggestions should show up while typing
    "editor.quickSuggestions": { "other": false, "comments": false, "strings": false },

    // Controls if suggestions should be accepted with "Enter" - in addition to "Tab". Helps to avoid ambiguity between inserting new lines and accepting suggestions.
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",

    // Controls the delay in ms after which quick suggestions will show up.
    "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,

    // Enable word based suggestions
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
}
```

Comment: I'm likely using a new version since this was written but for me `"editor.quickSuggestions"` is an object where I can tweak 3 sub-values: `{
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
  }`. Also, maybe VS Code is smart enough to see `"editor.quickSuggestions": false` and set all 3 to false

Comment: I was not able to follow the instructions. Please improve the answer

Comment: `acceptSuggestionOnEnter` should now be set to `"off"` as of recent versions.

Comment: I can't stand `wordBasedSuggestions`, that one tends to re-suggest the same spelling errors / typos made in the past; "Here's a function name that looks deceptively similar to a real one, but it isn't!"

Comment: `acceptSuggestionOnEnter` still is `on` by default for me. Ahhhh, what a sigh of relief to turn that off... I think I'll go bake some cookies with bananas in them...

Answer (score 37):

This works for me as of 2019-May-17.

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
"editor.hover.enabled": false,
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
"editor.quickSuggestions": false,
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
```

Comment: Add this to disable hover tooltips: `"editor.hover.enabled": false`

Comment: Perhaps add a little more context? E.g., where should that be added? A file or a UI element somewhere? If a file, where is it exactly (or how can it be opened)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen More context isn't really needed. If you're unsure how to update settings in VSCode, then perusing the VSCode settings page might be helpful. Here's what a < 10 second Internet search produced: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: FINALLY after trying all the other suggestions, THIS ONE WORKS! Thank you Charlie.

Comment: Awesome! acceptSuggestionOnEnter This worked for me :)

Answer (score 32):

This isn't the correct answer, but it might be an even better option.  Increase:

Editor: Quick Suggestions Delay

from 50 ms (default) to 500-1000 ms.

In this case, you'll have half a second to beat the autocomplete option, which may be enough for 95% of the time, and you won't lose the functionality that you might want in some cases.

Comment: Great answer. I did that. You could set it to an even higher number and challenge yourself to see if you can autocomplete faster than the machine ;-)

Comment: "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 1000000000 :)

Answer (score 9):

In the current version of Visual Studio Code, add this to your user settings:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions.other": false
```

This disables most of the spurious suggestions.

Comment: this configuration doesn't work on vscode 1.69.1

Answer (score 7):

Add this to settings.json

"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,

Answer (score 6):

I disabled mine by going to `Settings` > `Text Editor` > `Suggestions` > `Inline Suggest: Enabled` and unticking the box.

(Update) This is overwritten by the language settings, so you have make a new more changes. This post shows how to disable suggestions for Plain Text, but you can follow the steps to change the setting for all languages. [How to disable visual studio code dropdown suggestions in plain text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819876/how-to-disable-visual-studio-code-dropdown-suggestions-in-plain-text-files)

[image: Examples]

Answer (score 3):

Note: To open [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson), run `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). To open defaultSettings.json, use `Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)`, to open keybindings.json, use `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`, and to open defaultKeybindings.json, use `Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`. You need to save after editing these files. Note that many settings support being [overridden for](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings) specific [language modes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers).

#### To prevent suggestions from appearing while typing

In settings.json:

```json
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": "off",
    "comments": "off",
    "strings": "off"
},
"[dockerfile][json][json]": {
    // check defaultSettings.json or Settings UI to see which languages override editor.quickSuggestions and add them to the above list.
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": "off",
        "comments": "off",
        "strings": "off"
    },
},
```

#### To unbind default keybindings that *trigger* suggestions:

("trigger" means to make the suggestion widget / inline suggestions appear)

These might change in the future. You can search for these command IDs in defaultKeybindings.json to see what they are bound to. Put the following in keybindings.json:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+i",
    "command": "-editor.action.triggerSuggest",
},
{
    "key": "cmd+i",
    "command": "-editor.action.triggerSuggest",
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+space",
    "command": "-editor.action.triggerSuggest",
},
{
    "key": "cmd+space",
    "command": "-editor.action.triggerSuggest",
},
// editor.action.inlineSuggest.trigger currently not bound to anything by default
```

See also:

```json
"editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": false,
"editor.suggest.preview": false,
// "editor.inlineSuggest.suppressSuggestions": false
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none",
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": "off",
"editor.suggest.show*": true, // replace "*" with the thing you don't want to show. You can trigger suggestions here to see the list of options.

"debug.console.historySuggestions": false,
"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.suggestEnabled": false,
"workbench.commandPalette.experimental.suggestCommands": false,
```

#### To unbind default keybindings that *accept* suggestions:

("accept" means to confirm usage of the selected suggestion option from the suggestion widget / inline suggestion widget)

In settings.json:

```json
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
// "debug.console.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
```

In keybindings.json:

```json
{"key": "tab",         "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestion",},
{"key": "enter",       "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestion",},
{"key": "shift+tab",   "command": "-acceptAlternativeSelectedSuggestion",},
{"key": "shift+enter", "command": "-acceptAlternativeSelectedSuggestion",},
{"key": "tab",         "command": "-insertNextSuggestion",},
{"key": "shift+tab",   "command": "-insertPrevSuggestion",},
{"key": "tab",         "command": "-editor.action.inlineSuggest.commit",},
{"key": "ctrl+right",  "command": "-editor.action.inlineSuggest.acceptNextWord",},
{"key": "cmd+right",   "command": "-editor.action.inlineSuggest.acceptNextWord",},
{"key": "tab",         "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.acceptSelectedSuggestion",},
{"key": "enter",       "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.acceptSelectedSuggestion",},
// I'd list things for extensions like GitHub Copilot, but at that point... why would you be using those extensions? :P
```

#### To prevent automatic pairings

Since the question post mentioned `case` causing `end` to appear in SQL, see also these settings, or search for "autoclosing" in the Settings UI.

```json
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": "multiFile",
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "never",
"editor.autoClosingComments": "never",
"editor.autoClosingOvertype": "never",
"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never",
"html.autoClosingTags": false,
"javascript.autoClosingTags": false,
"typescript.autoClosingTags": false,
```

---

Note that you'll still be able to trigger suggestions and inline suggestions from the command palette.

Answer (score 2):

Here is up to date solution:

```
"editor.suggest.showClasses": false,
"editor.suggest.showColors": false,
"editor.suggest.showConstants": false,
"editor.suggest.showConstructors": false,
"editor.suggest.showCustomcolors": false,
"editor.suggest.showDeprecated": false,
"editor.suggest.showEnumMembers": false,
"editor.suggest.showEnums": false,
"editor.suggest.showEvents": false,
"editor.suggest.showFields": false,
"editor.suggest.showFiles": false,
"editor.suggest.showFolders": false,
"editor.suggest.showFunctions": false,
"editor.suggest.showInterfaces": false,
"editor.suggest.showIssues": false,
"editor.suggest.showKeywords": false,
"editor.suggest.showMethods": false,
"editor.suggest.showModules": false,
"editor.suggest.showOperators": false,
"editor.suggest.showProperties": false,
"editor.suggest.showReferences": false,
"editor.suggest.showSnippets": false,
"editor.suggest.showStructs": false,
"editor.suggest.showTypeParameters": false,
"editor.suggest.showVariables": false,
"editor.suggest.showValues": false,
"editor.suggest.showWords": false,
"editor.suggest.showUsers": false,
"editor.suggest.showUnits": false,

// controls bracket auto closing
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "never",

// controls  specific languages tag auto closing
"html.autoClosingTags": false,
"javascript.autoClosingTags": false,
"typescript.autoClosingTags": false
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Disable "Visual Studio IntelliCode" extension while working on SQL files. This might be a better option than changing settings that are useful for other files.