# How can I set the Emmet priority of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to write some HTML files. But there are some problems in it that i can't figure out.

When I write a `p` or `i` word and then use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to trigger Emmet, it always triggers the words like 'page' and 'id'.

[image]

How should I to improve the priority of Emmet?

Visual Studio Code version: 1.9.1 in Windows 7

Emmet setting:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911977/prevent-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code).

Just add the following to your settings, and it'll disable the IntelliSense popup as you type. If you want to see it, you can just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": false
```