# How to disable visual studio code dropdown suggestions in plain text files

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to disable Visual Studio Code dropdown suggestions? It's very annoying especially in plain text files. Is there any setting that disables this feature for some file extensions like `.txt` but doesn't for other extensions? Or is there any vscode extension that helps controling this feature?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To customize your editor by language, run the global command **Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings**

```
"[plaintext]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": false,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": false
    }
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings

Answer (score 0):

In File -> Preferences -> settings (ctrl+)

Look for `@lang:plaintext quick suggestions`

And turn them off!