# VS code suggestion box disable

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't seem to find the way to disable suggestions in VS code. I'm not even sure if the [boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXQIw.png) that show in the code are called suggestions, but I really want to disable these. They are covering literally almost half of my code. Does anyone know how to disable these [boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXQIw.png)?

Comment: It's called intellisense I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911977/prevent-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top box is `parameterHinits`, and the bottom box is `quickSuggestions`.

I think [this](https://blog.shawnhyde.com/post/2019/02/16/how-to-disable-popup-tips-in-visual-studio-code) can solve your problem.

If you don't want quick suggestions, you can set:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
}
```

But I think that is unnecessary, since you can just set a longer `editor.quickSuggestionsDelay`.

*tips: You can always toggle quick suggestion using `ctrl` + `space`*