# How to stop coerced autocomplete/suggestion in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, autosuggest

When I write a code in VS Code it's frequently giving me autosuggestion which is great, but sometimes the very specific thing I'm looking for is not there and I want to discard that suggestion and keep going with what I'm writing. when I press the space bar or the tab key the autosuggestion will take a place; I don't want that, I want to discard the suggestion without disabling the feature.

Comment: Press escape instead (this also works for a bunch of other popups in a variety of programs)

Comment: @ChrisG I appreciate your suggestion but I want a much easier to disable this from the settings. hitting the escape key every time is quite unproductive.

Comment: When I press Space it types a space. The window disappears. Even if that's not the case for you, what type of solution are you imagining? You don't want to disable it completely, and there's no actual AI yet, so do you just want a different key?

Comment: will at least I want the space bar to make it disappear the same way it did it with you, but my space bar autocompletes it.

Comment: It might be an extension you've installed. For me only `enter` inserts suggestion (which controlled by settings in `text editor` -> `suggestions`), not `space` or `tab`

Comment: Is there a way to make the suggestion window disappear? other than the escape key. like making the space bar have the functionality of the escape key. @vanowm

Comment: @user5734311 Congratulations! You have solved it! (for me anyway)

Comment: Well, actually, I might also want to permanently disable it, except when i press CTRL+ENTER or something, but I already saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206033/vs-code-suggestion-box-disable , and I was wondering what was the easyway to get rid of it without moving the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings**, and in the **Text Editor > Suggestions** section there will be:

> Editor: Accept Suggestion on Commit Character

Un-tick this checkbox and the suggestion will not be completed anymore on characters such as `;` or `(` etc.