# How to get rid of that annoying text box that appears after an autocomplete inside of which VSCode's intellisense does not work?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, editor, intellisense

I'm coding Golang in the screenshot. This box only appears after an auto-complete of a function or a struct happens and inside it the intellisense simply will not work.

How can I get rid of it? It's really bothering me and taking my time away in a somehow useless way because I just want to make use of the auto-complete but I have to press `esc` two times to turn off this box.

[image: Annoying box referenced in the question]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent autocomplete in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911977/prevent-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your problem. I tried with Code 1.41.1 and ms-vscode.go plugin version 0.12.0 on a Mac.

BUT, I found this [issue on vscode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28380#issuecomment-307514776) that works for me.
Basically, add the following to your settings. `"editor.parameterHints": false`