# Disable autocomplete from activating when I press enter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The title says it all.
When I type something in vs code (I am programming with python if that helps) and the autocomplete thing with all of the suggestions comes, even when I have already typed the line out and press enter to go to the next line, it just autocompletes the already autocomplete line of code.
I want to prevent vs code from autocompleting my code when I press enter. Is there a way to do that?

Edit: I have now come to the conclusion that my question was not very good, and it's a lot easier to just get on with it. A simple solution is just to press space after finishing a line of code, as that will get rid of the autocomplete window

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent autocomplete in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911977/prevent-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @Daniel F. -The auto-completion function in VSCode is very helpful for us to edit the code. If you don't want to enter the recommended options when you click "Enter" to wrap, you can click "Space" before clicking "Enter".

Comment: @JillCheng Yes that is a good tip. I have now learned to get over it, because it is just easier to press Space than to look for some complicated way to fix this 'problem'. Now, it doesn't even seem like a big problem anymore because I have gotten used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the Auto-Complete plugin for VS Code, or press `Ctrl+Space` to open the autocomplete options.