# Move Cursor Down? VS Code Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to move my input cursor down 1 line.

**Is there a way to bind cursor movement in the keyboard shortcuts interface?**

*Update:* I have actually found myself in Notepad++ whenever I'm just too tired to wrestle with my text cursor...

---

*So Far*

In other software, I use the `down arrow`. In VS Code, this scrolls auto-fill suggestions.

Formerly, I used a two-key combination: `left arrow` and `down arrow`, one to cancel suggestions, one to move the cursor. This no longer works. Suggestions persist.

I've looked everywhere for an answer. There are 0 alternatives, correct? The *move cursor down* exclusive functionality is simply not available in any way in the current version of VS Code.
Non-configurably eliminated from the software's design.

---

*Inadequate Solutions*

- I can hit `escape`, but like the mouse, that means lifting one hand. When editing dozens of lines of index assignations (ugly optimization, don't ask), my arm actually starts to burn from the rapid movements. The process is painfully slow.
- I cannot disable suggestions or summon them with `ctrl`+`space`, because I use them with every identifier I type (via `tab`), multiple times per line.

Comment: Maybe try pressing `esc` which will close intellisense before pressing down?

Comment: Like using the mouse, that makes me lift one hand off the keys.  
I was hoping to bind movement, maybe to the right shift and right ctrl? That way I can use my left pinky. Of course, if there's a built-in way, I'd rather use that.  
(And I can't just disable intellisense, I use it all the time...)

Comment: Not an answer but check this one might help (https://stackoverflow.com/q/32911977/1547449) My idea is to disable autocomplete and when you need it you just click (CTRL + Space)

Comment: @iYazee6 that's the best compromise I've seen. Thank you. I really, really want to be able to move the cursor freely and scroll / select suggestions freely; one keystroke in either case. All this double-tapping and triple-tapping feels so silly. These actions would just need to be exposed to the keyboard shortcut binding interface. Am I really the only one who cares? Maybe so... Maybe it's just not as important as I think it is.