# test autocompletes to TestWatcher in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs

I am using VSCode to create and manage some Jest tests in a project.

Whenever I start to type `test` in a clean file, `test` autocompletes to `TestWatcher` and VSCode prepends the line `import { TestWatcher } from "jest";` to the file.

I am trying to figure out what is causing this to happen and how to either eliminate it or use it efficiently.  Web searches yielded pretty vague results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that helped me to resolve it is `npm i @types/jest --save-dev`. But it seems to be a crunch to install something related to typescript when what I want to do is write pure JS.

*UPD*
Make sure you have installed jest as well. For me, it works only if both `jest` and `@types/jest` are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Watch this question [Prevent autocomplete in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911977/prevent-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code)

`cmd + ,` to call out `settings`. Search for `acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter`, then toggle it out.

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```